# Can I upgrade my computer's RAM?

Tags: laptop, memory, asus-laptop, ramdisk, parameters

My computer bought in 2013 and 4Gb memory, now I want to [upgrade RAM](https://downloadram.net/) for my computer to use smoother, My Computer is asus k56CM core i5 laptop. I want to use it more smoothly, and I use downloadram.net blog to download more ram. and the unexpected ending!

Comment: This page says up to 8GB RAM: https://www.asus.com/Laptops/K56CM/specifications/

Comment: Should be possible depending on the motherboard.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  Please edit your Question to better match the actual question you're  asking.  For instance, remove "ramdisk" and "parameters".  If you know how many RAM slots you have and how they are occupied (for example, you might have 2 slots both with 2 GB sticks), then also put that info in the Question.  When the Question is more precise, then you are likely to get better answers, and also future readers will be able to use the question/answer better.

Answer (score 1):

This laptop has 2 x SO-DIMM socket. It means you can upgrade your computer's RAM.  But it is a DDR3 RAM.
Increase RAM can make your PC more smoothly when run large programs.
But if you just use it for business, there is no need to upgrade RAM.
A better way to faster your PC is to install a **SSD**. It is better than increase RAM.
Software will open much faster than before. I have installed SSD in my PC, my OS run faster than before. Strongly suggest you to install SSD.

Answer (score -2):

You can upgrade RAM, 8Gb for sure, but need to know the type of existing RAM to use the same RAM that is supported by the motherboard.